# Comparative statistics of (trivariate) random event

Tags: normal-distribution

**Problem:**
I'm interested in studying the probability of an event involving a random vector.

Specifically, I'm interested in

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a}Pr\left(X > \frac{Y-a}{Z} \right)$$

where $a$ is a non-random parameter, and the vector $(X, Y, Z) \sim$ Normal $(\mu, \Sigma)$
for $\mu=(0,0,0)$ and 
$\Sigma=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0.5 & 0.5 \\
 0.5 & 1 & 0 \\
 0.5 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

**What I have:**

Simulations tell me that the above partial derivative is non-monotonic, i.e. increasing the value of $a$ first increases the probability of the event, and then decreases it. Here is a simulation for $a\in[0,3].$

[image: Simulation]

I can see that this is likely coming from the fact that $Z$ takes value along the real line, so the effect of $a$ flips with the sign of $Z$.

**Question**
I struggle to understand exactly what is going on here from a *distributional* point of view. What determines the point of inflection? I don't need an analytical solution – just some intuition.